# Is ArrayList of ArrayList similar to a 2D array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

Is an 
`ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> numbers;` like a 2D array of ints `int[][] numbers;`?
Or are these stored completely different from one another?

Comment: Apart that the first one can grow dynamically, both are similars.

Comment: both are dissimilar in memory allocation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a structure with two dimensions, so it is [][]-like, yet there is one very important difference: if you allocate a two-dimensional array in one step you'll get **same size** in the second dimension for all elements of the first dimension:

```
int[][] arrayOfInts = new int[5][4];

for (int[] second : arrayOfInts) {
   System.out.println(second.length);
}
```

prints 5 times a "4".

Using ArrayList of ArrayLists all elements of the second dimension may have different size.

As pointed out by jlordo: an array of ints may also have the second dimension of different lengths if it is created dynamically:

```
int[][] anotherArray = new int[5][];

for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
  anotherArray[i] = new int[i];
}
```

in which case a NullPointerException can be throws if the second dimension were accessed before being intialized, like:

```
int[][] yetAnotherArray = new int[5][];
System.out.println(yetAnotherArray[2][3]);
```

The other difference: after allocating a int[x][y] the memory for all its elements in both dimension is allocated from the very first moment. In ArrayList of ArrayLists the memory needed for the lists is allocated, but the memory needed for its elements will be used not before you create their content. So a similar code as before will print **nothing**, because at the beginning there will not be even a single element in the first ArrayList.

In order to have the second dimension you first have to create all ArrayLists of the second dimension:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> arrayOfArrays = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
for (int i=0; i < 5; i++) {
    arrayOfArrays.add(new ArrayList<Integer>();
}
```

Further on the accessing side:

```
int[][] arrayOfInts = new int[5][4];
System.out.println(arrayOfInts[2][3]);
```

prints 0 because all of the memory is already allocated. The access is safe both in addressing the dimensions and its value, because it is of a primitive type.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> arrayOfArrays = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
for (int i=0; i < 5; i++) {
    arrayOfArrays.add(new ArrayList<Integer>();
}
System.out.println(first.get(2).get(3));
```

throws ArrayOutOfBoundsException. You have to check the size of the elements before accessing them.

Now there is also one important difference between int[][] and Integer[][]: primitive types always have values, so after allocating int[4][5] you'll have **0** for unitialized elements. Integer[4][5] contain objects, so unitialized elements will have **null** instead.

Comment: you can also have an `int[][]` with different sizes in second dimension.

Comment: and you'll get NPEs when accessing uninitialized elements in second dimension with `int[][]`.

Comment: the first: true, if creating the second dimension dynamically. the second: not true, all primitive types have values immediately. In case if int it is 0. I'll edit the answer appropriately.

Comment: to prove my second point: try this: `int[][] a = new int[3][]; a[1][1] = 7;`

Comment: I take my objection back - you are right, thank you for pointing out. To my defence: the content and examples made use of an immediate allocating using [x][y] in which case both the dimensions are same and accessing is safe of both out of bounds as well as null pointer exception. Yet for the answer to be useful and complete you remarks need to be taken into account, which I did : giving you the tribute where tribute is due.

Comment: now I turned my -1 to a +1 ;) It first sounded like you were saying `int[][]` are always _rectangular_, and esp. people learning to code shouldn't read anything wrong. Now you have a great answer explaining all possibilities.

Comment: oo makes sense now i was reading it over and over and got confused at some point, thanks very much guys/girls!

Answer (score 3):

It is similar to `Integer[][]`, which is somewhat different to `int[][]`.

Also `ArrayList` provides additional facilities over what an array does, such as the ability to grow dynamically, and manage separate notions of *size* and *capacity*.

Answer (score 1):

Not fully sure but the memory allocation would be **different** in both cases. The primitive array `int[][]` will be allocated in **stack** while the `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>` will be allocated in **Heap**.